# Directed graph using digraph in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, directed-graph

The default of the directed graphs created by the function digraph in Matlab have the arrowhead in the middle of the lines between nodes. Is there a way to modify the plot of digraph so the arrow is at the end of the line instead?

For example:

```
A = ones(4) - diag([1 1 1 1])
G = digraph(A)
plot(G)
```

Gives:

[image]

As can be seen, the arrowhead is in the middle of the line, but I want the arrowhead to be at the end or each line.

Comment: Can you give any code, or an example of what you have and what you want? There's not much context to go on.

Comment: Seeing your edit, so the arrows which go from each node, you wish to have at the end of the line, not in the middle of the line?

Comment: I only found GraphPlot properties ```ArrowSize``` and ```ShowArrows```. There is probably no option to do it in such an object.